# wxPython button widget won't move

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm building a simple webcam program to take pictures. Right now, I'm completing the GUI, and my wxPython button won't move even when it's explicitly placed. I've tried following the basic wxPython [tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#Layout__Management) and it's not working. Could it be that my bitmap is not 'on' the panel?

Here's my code:

```
import wx
import cv2

class webcamWindow(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, camera, fps=10):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        wx.Button(panel, -1, "Capture", (210,660))

        self.camera = camera
        ret_value, frame = self.camera.read()
        height, width = frame.shape[:2]
        parent.SetSize((width, (height+75)))

        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(width, height, frame)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(1000./fps)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.NextFrame)

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0)
    def NextFrame(self, e):
        ret_value, frame = self.camera.read()
        if ret_value:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            self.bmp.CopyFromBuffer(frame)
            self.Refresh()

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Webcam")
cap = webcamWindow(frame, camera)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create `Panel` only for webcam image and then I use it in frame with `Button`

```
import wx
import cv2

#---------------------------------------------------------------------- 

class webcamPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, camera, fps=10):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.camera = camera

        ret_value, frame = self.camera.read()
        height, width = frame.shape[:2]

        # resize panel with camera image
        self.SetSize( (width, height) )

        # resize main window
        self.GetParent().GetParent().SetSize( (width, height+75) )

        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(width, height, frame)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(1000./fps)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.NextFrame)

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0)

    def NextFrame(self, e):
        ret_value, frame = self.camera.read()
        if ret_value:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            self.bmp.CopyFromBuffer(frame)
            self.Refresh()

#---------------------------------------------------------------------- 

class webcamWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, camera, fps=10):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        # add panel with webcam image
        self.webcampanel = webcamPanel(self.panel, camera)

        # get size of webcam panel
        webcampanelsize = self.webcampanel.GetSize()

        # put button below webcam panel
        self.but = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Capture", pos=(0, webcampanelsize.height), size=(webcampanelsize.width,75))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

app = wx.App()
cap = webcamWindow(camera)
cap.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

If you use some layout manager in `Frame` you will not have to calculate `Button` position.

In place of `wx.Panel` you could use `wx.Window` or `wx.Control`. See: [Class hierarchy](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html)

Comment: I'm trying to understand this properly. So webcamWindow is your parent and you have a class of webcamPanel under it via self.webcampanel? I'm sorry if this is an easy question; I'm new to wxPython and it's pretty confusing for me.

Comment: Yes, `webcamWindow(wx.Frame)` is main window. It has `self.panel` to put other widgets side by side. One widget is `wx.Button`. Another widget is `webcamPanel(wx.Panel)` which use `onPaint` to draw image from camera. Now you can even use many webcamPanel to show images from many cameras at the same time :)

Comment: Ah thank you so much! wxPython is quite difficult to read and picture. I think I understand what you did though!